# Filter query results where original fee and reversals wash to zero

Tags: cognos-10

In Cognos 10 query, What method is best to remove items from list below 
where the Fee charged and the fee assessed Tran Amounts are a wash, ie, sum to zero?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detail filter, property after aggregation

```
Total ([Tran Amount] for [Loan#]) <> 0
```

Comment: @ VAI Jason:  That works except when there are additional trans that don't wash. If I incorporate the Due date it then seems to work great: Total ([Tran_Amt] for [Loan#],[Due_Date]) <>0 Thanks! – ORLANDO VAZQUEZ 44 mins ago    Delete